# How to store selected radio buttons on each page into database accordingly using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, html

Given this table in my database:

```
|AnswerID|QuestionID|AnswerText|
|21      |2         |User      |
|22      |2         |Admin     |
|23      |2         |Guest     |
|24      |2         |User2     |
```

I have created a quiz using `PAGINATION` to display individual question and its options on each of the page. Example code snippet is as shown below:

```
$questionID=0;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo $list['QuestionID'] . ":" . $list['QuestionText'] . "<br/>";  
$questionID=$list['QuestionID'];
}
$optionsquery="SELECT AnswerText,AnswerID FROM Options Where QuestionID=".$questionID;
$optionsresult=mysql_query($optionsquery) or die ('Query failed:'. mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($optionsresult))
{
echo "<br>";
echo "<input type='radio' id='radio-" . $row["QuestionID"] . "-" 
      . $row["AnswerID"] . "' name='" . $row["QuestionID"] 
      . "' value='" . $row["AnswerID"] . "' /> 
      <label for='radio-" . $row["QuestionID"] . "-" . $row["AnswerID"] . "'>" 
      . $row["AnswerText"] ."</label><br/>";
      echo "<br>";
}
```

Here is my objective. Given this relationship AnswerID<->AnswerText, 
I want to store the selected radio chosen by the user into my database table of the following format :

```
|StudentID|QuestionID(e.g: 1)|QuestionID(e.g: 2)|
|678D     |AnswerID(e.g: 11) |AnswerID(e.g: 22) | 
|681D     |AnswerID(e.g: 14) |AnswerID(e.g: 23) |
```

As shown in the above,I am not hard-coding the questions and options for each page,they are rather taken from my database of tables. All the codes are being written in only one single PHP file. I have googled (on PHP) but I am confused on how to go about achieving my objective. Any code(PHP) snippets will be helpful as I am at loss of ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you don't store it in that way (ie one question per column) .... You would be better creating a table that linked `student`, `question` and `answer` :

```
Student    question     answer 
678D       1            11 
678D       2            22  
681D       1            14 
681D       2            23
```

This gives you better flexibility - you can increase the number of questions easily for example.

To make processing a submitted form easier I would change the HTML output to this :

```
echo "<input type='radio' id='question[" . $row["QuestionID"] . "]' name='question[" .
$row["QuestionID"] ."]' value='" . $row["AnswerID"] . "' />";
```

This would produce inputs as an array which would maan processing them when submitted like this :

```
$questions = $_POST['question']; // this returns an array like questions[questionid]
foreach ($questions as $qid => $aid) {
    $query = 'INSERT INTO answertable(student,question,answer) VALUES
              ($sudentid,$qid,$aid)';
}
```

You would need to change the `answertable` to the name of the table you are using to record answers. And `$student` would be obtained from the current session (im guessing thats where you are storing it)

Comment: How should I organize the <form></form> tags (submit) button in this kinda of pagination environment? Is there a way to see the output of the answers I selected in another page before inserting them into the database? Thanks for your help so far, I'm learning new things :)

Comment: @Derek You can use the `<form>` tag however you like as the result table will keep a track of the answers to questions for you. To view the answers use "echo" to output them instead of adding them to the `insert` query

Comment: Hi, I tried implementing the following method as shown below,but however I still cant get the value of the selected value on each page and the selected value for each question is not saved when I navigate from one page to another. Could you advice me what is wrong? echo "<form method='post' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>";
session_start();$_SESSION['questions']=$_POST['question'];
 echo "<input type='submit' name='save' value='   Save   ' />";
echo $_SESSION['questions'];